# Cells getting locked in an unexplainable manner on Worksheet_Chnage event

Tags: excel, vba

I have a protected excel sheet that triggers Worksheet_Change code on entering contents in columns A,B,C etc. Each column does perform different validation. Unexplainably cells in Columns E and F only are getting locked on entering valid numerical values and pressing Enter on a blank cell. I have stepped through the code and couldn't find any code relating to locking of cells. The codes are quite long so I give below only those lines that are getting highlighted during the step through process.

```
ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("E:E")) Is Nothing And Target.Row > 4 Then 
    strUnitInput = Target.Cells.Value2
    strFolioNo = Cells(Target.Row, "A").Value2
    strFundName = Cells(Target.Row, "B").Value2
    strDateInput = CStr(Cells(Target.Row, "C").Value2)
    strTranType = Cells(Target.Row, "D").Value2
    If Len(strUnitInput) > 0 Then
    strUnitInput = Trim(strUnitInput)
    If strUnitInput = vbNullString Then
    ....
    ElseIf strFolioNo = vbNullString Then 
    ...
    ElseIf strFundName = vbNullString Then 
    ...
    ElseIf strDateInput = vbNullString Then 
    ...
    ElseIf strTranType = vbNullString Then 
    ...
    Else 'Validation of Unit field
        If IsNumeric(strUnitInput) Then
             If InStr(1, strUnitInput, "/", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, strUnitInput, "-", _
                           vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
             ...
             ElseIf CDbl(strUnitInput) <= 0 Then 'if user has entered zero or negative unit numbers
             ...
             Else 'User has entered positive unit numbers
                   If strTranType = "Sale" Or strTranType = "Switch Out" Or strTranType = "SWP" Then 
                      ...
                   Else
                        With Cells(Target.Row, "E")
                            .Value2 = CDbl(strUnitInput)
                            .ClearFormats
                            .NumberFormat = "#,##0.0000 ;[Black](#,##0.0000);- ;"
                        End With
                        Columns("E:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit
                        Application.EnableEvents = True
                        Cells(Target.Row, "F").Select
                        Application.EnableEvents = False
                 End If
          End If
      End If
   End If
End if
```

As you can see no code is pertaining to locking of cells. I have unchecked "Lock" checkbox under format Cells option for the entire columns of E and F several times. But on pressing F2 and Enter on existing cells, they are getting locked again. It would be a big help if someone could throw some light on the root cause.

Comment: Do you want any cells to be locked, or is it the whole sheet that is protected? You might try manually locking and unlocking all cells on the sheet, then run your macro and see what happens. Alternatively, you can perform that same action in your VBA code, just to guarantee the cells stay unlocked. (But honestly, you should only have to do this once unless you can find any other code that may be tripping you up.)

Comment: Cell protection is part of the cell formatting, so `Clearformats` will reset it to the default (which is usually Locked).

Comment: @ Rory - If you notice .ClearFormats is already present in the codes I have pasted above. Despite this, cells are getting locked.